# Log4net EventLogAppender only works in root logger, why?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have a console application, where I'm trying to log to Windows Event Log with **log4net** using `EventLogAppender`. I also have two `RollingFileAppender`s, but those are working properly.

The `RollingFileAppender`s are in the root logger, configured like this:

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderInfo" />      
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderDebug" />
</root>
```

The `EventLogAppender`s are in a logger called `EventLogger`, configured like this:

```
<logger Name="EventLogger">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppenderInfo"/>
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppenderError"/> 
</logger>
```

This way the `EventLogger` inherits the appenders from root. If I log something with `EventLogger`, it will be written to the log files as well. The reason why I've done it like this, because I don't want to spam the Windows Event Log with all the info entries, just the important ones. But I also want to log every error.

This is how I get the logger:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog eventLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EventLogger");
```

**The problem**

Configured like this, using the `eventlog` object to log something in any level, log4net doesn't write to the Windows Event Log, but it writes to the log files, so the appenders in root are working.

If I put the `EventLogAppender`s to the root, they are working, but they are also logging INFO level entries that I don't want to log to the Event Log.

I don't think this would be a permission issue, the source is already created, and accessible.

Here are the two `EventLogAppender`s, if anyone's curious:

```
<appender name="EventLogAppenderInfo" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
  <applicationName value="ApplicationName" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="INFO"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>

<appender name="EventLogAppenderError" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
  <applicationName value="ApplicationName" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <IgnoresException value="False"/>
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="WARN" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

I can't think of anything why log4net doing this, if anyone has a solution, it would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a case-sensitive issue.

```
<logger Name="EventLogger">
```

should be

```
<logger name="EventLogger">
```

Comment: Stupid me... I broke my head for two hours to figure out it's the capital `N` which caused the issue...